# Can you use TypeScript decorators to add properties to a method call?

Tags: typescript, typescript1.5

Right now while using decorators the javascript seems to work (force compile and method is available), but the types are too strict.

As you can see [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=declare%20var%20_%3A%20any%3B%0Aexport%20function%20Throttle(milli%3A%20number)%20%7B%0A%09interface%20Throttled%20extends%20Function%20%7B%0A%09%09%09now%3A%20Function%0A%09%7D%0A%09return%20function%3CT%20extends%20Throttled%3E(target%3A%20Object%2C%20propertyKey%3A%20string%2C%20descriptor%3A%20TypedPropertyDescriptor%3CFunction%3E)%3A%20TypedPropertyDescriptor%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%09%09%09let%20originalMethod%20%3D%20descriptor.value%3B%0A%09%09%09%2F%2F%20NOTE%3A%20Do%20not%20use%20arrow%20syntax%20here.%20Use%20a%20function%20expression%20in%0A%09%09%09%2F%2F%20order%20to%20use%20the%20correct%20value%20of%20%60this%60%20in%20this%20method%0A%09%09%09descriptor.value%20%3D%20%3Cany%3E_.throttle(function()%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09originalMethod.apply(this%2C%20arguments)%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%2C%20milli)%3B%0A%09%09%09(%3CThrottled%3Edescriptor.value).now%20%3D%20%3Cany%3Efunction()%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09originalMethod.apply(this%2C%20arguments)%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%3B%0A%09%09%09return%20%3CTypedPropertyDescriptor%3CT%3E%3Edescriptor%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%09%0A%0A%0A%09class%20Ctrl%20%7B%0A%0A%09%09constructor(scope%3A%20any)%20%7B%20%0A%09%09%20%20%20%20scope.%24watch(%22foo%22%2C%20this.throttledByClassWatch)%3B%0A%09%09%09this.throttledByClassWatch.now()%20%2F%2Funrecommended%20now%20call%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%40Throttle(100000)%0A%09%09private%20throttledByClassWatch()%20%7B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%0A) the following does not compile:

```
declare var _: any;
export function Throttle(milli: number) {
    interface Throttled extends Function {
            now: Function
    }
    return function<T extends Throttled>(target: Object, propertyKey: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<Function>): TypedPropertyDescriptor<T> {
            let originalMethod = descriptor.value;
            // NOTE: Do not use arrow syntax here. Use a function expression in
            // order to use the correct value of `this` in this method
            descriptor.value = <any>_.throttle(function() {
                originalMethod.apply(this, arguments);
            }, milli);
            (<Throttled>descriptor.value).now = <any>function() {
                originalMethod.apply(this, arguments);
            };
            return <TypedPropertyDescriptor<T>>descriptor;
        }
}

class Ctrl {

    constructor(scope: any) { 
        scope.$watch("foo", this.throttledByClassWatch);
        this.throttledByClassWatch.now() //unrecommended now call
    }
    @Throttle(100000)
    private throttledByClassWatch() {
    }
}
```

I might have the types a little wrong but I have tried many other permutations. It seems to be because the expected type is

```
declare type MethodDecorator = <T>(target: Object, propertyKey: string | symbol, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<T>) => TypedPropertyDescriptor<T> | void;
```

and so the input T must match the output T.

Ideally the `now` could also inherit the generic type `T` so it could be type checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript's type system isn't able to describe properties on methods.

What you could do is something along these lines:

```
interface Throttled extends Function {
    now: Function;
}

function Throttle(milli: number) {
    return function(target: Object, propertyKey: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>) {
        let originalMethod = descriptor.value;

        descriptor.value = _.throttle(function() {
            originalMethod.apply(this, arguments);
        }, milli);

        (<Throttled>descriptor.value).now = function() {
            originalMethod.apply(this, arguments);
        };

        return descriptor;
    };
}

class Ctrl {
    constructor(scope: any) {
        this.runNow(this.throttledByClassWatch);
    }

    @Throttle(100000)
    private throttledByClassWatch() {
    }

    private runNow(method: Function, ...args: any[]) {
        (method as Throttled).now.apply(this, args);
    }
}
```

Basically, have a reusable function that abstracts away calling `.now()` on throttled methods.

Comment: Thanks, I used this approach. There is also this issue that relates https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881